# Visual C++ 2022, Microsoft Store and MSIX manifest question

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

**Hi!**

Would someone answer my question, please?
I have a Visual C++ application linked against C++ DLL Runtime.
It is converted to Microsoft Store app by MSIX Packaging Tool.
The question is about MSIX manifest:
Is this fragment of XML correct for Windows SDK 10.0.19041.0 and VC+ 2022?

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.19041.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.22000.376" />
<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.30035.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
```

I highly appreciate the support.

Comment: SDK looks correct - no idea about the VCLibs - it's really hard to find out what the version numbers are supposed to be, as they're not listed anywhere, and because they don't seem to match the actual VC++ runtime numbers (Visual Studio 2022 is 14.31.31103.0). https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: Actually, found a bit more info... will move this to an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.19041.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.22000.376" />
```

`TargetDeviceFamily` is telling the AppInstaller runtime that the minimum version that you have tested the app with is 10.0.19041, i.e. May 2020 Update (2004 / 20H1). It's not directly connected to the SDK that you've compiled with (as you could target a much newer SDK, but carefully avoid calling newer APIs unless they're available).

```
<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.30035.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
```

`PackageDependency` is harder to find information on, as the version numbers don't appear to be listed anywhere (and don't match the Visual Studio 2022 C++ runtime version of `14.31.31103.0`). However, I found [the following page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/redistribution#universal-windows-apps-and-windows-store-apps), which describes "Side-loading of Universal Windows Apps" and lists `[Program Files (x86)]\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop\14.0\Appx\Retail\`. Taking a look around those directories, I can see the following file:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop\14.0\SDKManifest.xml`

The file contains the following:

```
<FileList TargetPlatform="UAP" 
  FrameworkIdentity-Debug = "Name = Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug.UWPDesktop, MinVersion = 14.0.30035.0, Publisher = 'CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US'" 
  FrameworkIdentity-Retail = "Name = Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop, MinVersion = 14.0.30035.0, Publisher = 'CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US'" 
  MinVSVersion = "14.0" 
  TargetPlatformMinVersion="10.0.0.0" 
  TargetPlatformVersion="10.0.0.0" 
  DisplayName = "Visual C++ 2015-2019 UWP Desktop Runtime for native apps" 
  AppliesTo = "WindowsAppContainer + (Managed | Javascript | Native)" 
  AppX-Debug-ARM = ".\AppX\Debug\ARM\Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.Debug.14.00.Desktop.appx" 
  AppX-Debug-ARM64 = ".\AppX\Debug\ARM64\Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM64.Debug.14.00.Desktop.appx" 
  AppX-Debug-x86 = ".\AppX\Debug\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.Desktop.appx" 
  AppX-Debug-x64 = ".\AppX\Debug\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.Desktop.appx" 
  AppX-Retail-ARM = ".\AppX\Retail\ARM\Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.14.00.Desktop.appx" 
  AppX-Retail-ARM64 = ".\AppX\Retail\ARM64\Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM64.14.00.Desktop.appx" 
  AppX-Retail-x86 = ".\AppX\Retail\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.14.00.Desktop.appx" 
  AppX-Retail-x64 = ".\AppX\Retail\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx" 
  SupportsMultipleVersions="Error" 
  SupportedArchitectures="x86;x64;ARM;ARM64"> 
 </FileList>
```

As you can see, it mentions `14.0.30035.0`. I have Visual Studio 2022 installed (along with Visual Studio 2019) so I'm going to *assume* that `14.0.30035.0` relates to the most recent version.

**Additional:** Perhaps not the best assumption, using PowerShell I can see what versions are currently installed:

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name "*VCLib*" | Select-Object -Property Name, Version, Architecture | Where-Object {$_.Architecture -eq 'X64'}

Name                                     Version      Architecture
----                                     -------      ------------
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00                  14.0.27810.0          X64
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00                  14.0.29231.0          X64
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug.UWPDesktop 14.0.29231.0          X64
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug            14.0.29231.0          X64
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00                  14.0.30035.0          X64
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop       14.0.30035.0          X64
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00                  14.0.30704.0          X64
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop       14.0.30704.0          X64
```

As you can see, the highest version number actually installed on my machine is `14.0.30704.0`.

**Further:** I did some experimentation and found that building an app with Visual Studio 2022, and packaging as an MSIX with a dependency on `14.0.30035.0` will run on a clean installation of Windows 10 2004 (May 2020). So I think `14.0.30035.0` is the correct runtime for Visual Studio 2022.